# Where i can get the steps to run sonarqube code analyser for C++ code on linux

Tags: c++, linux, sonarqube

Below is the log when i run the sonar runner:

> [OMC3_B12_LINUX6] sonar@omclinux03> ./sonar-runner
>   SonarQube Runner 2.4
>   Java 1.6.0_22 Sun Microsystems Inc. (64-bit)
>   Linux 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 amd64
>   INFO: Runner configuration file: /home/sonar/sonar/sonar-runner-2.4/conf/sonar-r
>   unner.properties
>   INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
>   INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
>   INFO: Work directory: /home/sonar/sonar/sonar-runner-2.4/bin/./.sonar
>   ERROR: Sonar server 'http://localhost:9000' can not be reached
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Total time: 0.065s
>   Final Memory: 5M/964M
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>   ERROR: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   ERROR: Caused by: Connection refused
>   ERROR:
>   ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with t
>   he -e switch.
>   ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: Are you using the community plugin or the commercial, SonarSource plugin?

Comment: its community plugin

Answer (score 0):

Logs says sonnar-runner can not find a SonarQube instance running on the current machine and listening on port 9000:

> ERROR: Sonar server 'http://localhost:9000' can not be reached

Sonnar-runner needs a SonarQube instance to run an analysis. See the 4 first steps of "Get Started in Two Minutes" [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade)

C++ support in SonarQube is provided by a commercial plugin, so you should start by reading [its documentation](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/). There is a community plugin also, I think.

For the installation of SonarQube, which ever the platform, see the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation) and the getting started link above.

Comment: So Could you please give me a link or document , by which i can configure sonarQube for c++ on linux server.

Comment: C++ support in SonarQube is provided by a commercial plugin, so you should start by reading the [documentation of the plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/). There is a community plugin also, I think. For installation of SonarQube, which ever the platform, see the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation)